# PHP- Date function confusion in tamil format

Tags: php

I want like this in PHP date format

`$date1= 2012-02-22 15:31:01;` is to

புதன்கிழமை, 22 பெப்ரவரி 2012, 07:55.53 மு.ப GMT

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want but it can probably be solved with the [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions for php. Check out the documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

[strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) — Format a local time/date according to locale settings